# Skewness of the sample mean random varaiable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

> We have X1 , ... , Xn being independent and identically distributed random variables with mean μ, variance σ<sup>2</sup> and skewness γ. Show that the skewness of the sample mean M is <sup>γ</sup>⁄<sub>√n</sub>

Here is my incorrect reasoning:

We can assume that μ=0 and σ<sup>2</sup>=1 without loss of generality, that is if the Xj's are not standardised, we can standardise them. Then to determine the skewness of M we use the third standardised moment of M:

Skew(M) = E[<sup>(M - average.of.M)</sup>⁄<sub>stdev.of.M</sub>]<sup>3</sup>

average.of.M is unbiased so average.of.M = μ = 0.

stdev.of.M = sqrt[Var(M)] = sqrt[σ<sup>2</sup>/n] = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>sqrt(n)</sub>

So Skew(M) = E[sqrt(n)*M]<sup>3</sup> = n<sup>3/2</sup>E[M]<sup>3</sup>

M<sup>3</sup> = [<sup>(X1 + X2 + ... + Xn)</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>]<sup>3</sup> = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>n<sup>3</sup></sub>E[X1 + X2 + ... + Xn]<sup>3</sup>

[X1 + X2 + ... + Xn]<sup>3</sup> is made up of terms with coefficients 1, 3, and 6 so that it can be written in a general form of [X1 + X2 + ... + Xn]<sup>3</sup> = nX1<sup>3</sup> + 3n(n-1)X1<sup>3</sup> + 6(<sub>n</sub>C<sub>3</sub>)X1<sup>3</sup>

Plugging back into Skew(M), Skew(M) = n<sup>3/2</sup> $\times$ <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>n<sup>3</sup></sub>E[nX1<sup>3</sup> + 3n(n-1)X1<sup>3</sup> + 6(<sub>n</sub>C<sub>3</sub>)X1<sup>3</sup>]

Simplifying by using Linearity of Expectation where E[X1<sup>3</sup>] = γ and applying the Choose formula we get Skew(M) = γ $\times$ n<sup><sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub></sup>

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for information on formatting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors. One is probably merely typographical: The third power should be inside the square brackets – the way you've written it, it's just $E[M]^3=0^3=0$.

The conceptual error is that you replaced all monomials by $X_1^3$. The idea to replace them is good and correct, but you can only replace them by applying the permutations under which the problem is invariant; there's no way to transform e.g. $X_1X_2^2$ into $X_1^3$ by a permutation. A correct expression would have been

$$
nX_1^3+3n(n-1)X_1^2X_2+6\binom n3X_1X_2X_3\;,
$$

and the expectation values of the second and third terms vanish because they both contain a single variable.